# Is it possible to write on a properties file inside a .war?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I see a lot of how to read the file or locate it, but I've been trying to run Properties.store() and it simple does not modify the file.

I can read, get and set properties but store doesn't work. Should it work or is not meant to work?

If it doesn't work, how can I modify the file, so when the server restart those properties do not get lost?

Comment: use whatever IDE you're using to rebuild the project and then export back to a .war (if using eclipse. In the case of netbeans a 'clean and build' will cause it to update/export to the .war file) then republish to your container (aka server).

Comment: If you really want to do this then do not package your properties file inside the WAR or use an exploded deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; it's inside a WAR.

Technically you could un-zip it, modify it, zip it back up. But don't.

Properties like that should be stored in a DB, in JNDI, or in a file outside of the war.

Comment: ok, precise answer, and something my boss would clearly understand, thanks

Comment: @javaNoober Don't overestimate bosses ;)

Comment: could you point me on how the JNDI alternative should be implemented?

Comment: and I wasn't underestimating my boss, but he was saying "if you can read the file you should be able to modify it"

Comment: @javaNoober No no, don't *overestimate* his/her ability to understand. Anything. Ever. Here's an [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965061/how-can-i-store-jee-configuration-parameters-outside-of-an-ear-or-war) with a reference that may also provide additional ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Property files bundled inside a JAR are not meant to change because they make part of the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mess with unzipping/rezipping a WAR file, just as a piece of advice. I have done that in the past and it did not work so well.