# Confused on getting the path for writing a text file using a Servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I've the below project structure in my eclipse.

[image]

and my code in servlet is as below.

```
File entityFile = new File(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/EntityList/entities.txt");
FileWriter fout = new FileWriter(entityFile);
fout.write("The Content");
fout.close();
```

here basically I'm trying to write to a file available at `/EntityList/entities.txt`, but when I run this, I get the exception as below.

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [com.luis.servlets.WriteEntityToAFile] in context with path
>   [/LUISWebUI] threw exception java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   \LUISWebUI\EntityList\entities.txt (The system cannot find the path
>   specified)

I know that I'm going wrong with the path, Can someone please put me in the right direction.

**Update**

Apologies for the confusion.

I'm sending some data from jsp to servlet to write to the `entities.txt` file. I'm able to capture it in servlet(Cross checked it by doing sysout).

Comment: Where is this `/EntityList/entities.txt` located on the deployed server?

Comment: put `EntitiesList` inside WebContent` folder and use 

    InputStream stream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/EntitiesList/entities.txt");

Comment: @Ramanlfc, then how will I write to the entities.txt, sorry for the confusion, updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you have a typo problem, try `/EntitiesList/entities.txt` instead of `/EntityList/entities.txt`.

Also, move the `/EntitiesList/entities.txt` under `/WEB-INF/` for example, so that your `servlet` class can access it.

You can read a more detailed explanation [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app).

**Edit:**

About writing to file: your application will be packaged inside a `WAR` file so you won't be able to write to it, only read from it (more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408543/is-it-possible-to-write-on-a-properties-file-inside-a-war)).

But you can just use this way of creating directly a file outside the WAR and using this location to write your content (before that, make sure you have appropriate rights):

```
File entityFile = new File(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "entities.txt");
FileWriter fOut = new FileWriter(entityFile);
fOut.write("The Content");
fOut.close();
```

Or if you want the directory also, you'll have to execute some additional steps, create it first then specify the file name inside it where you want to write:

```
 File entityFolder = new File(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "EntitiesList");
 entityFolder.mkdir();
 File entityFile = new File(entityFolder, "entities.txt");
 FileWriter fOut = new FileWriter(entityFile);
 fOut.write("The Content");
 fOut.close();
```

Comment: how will I write to the entities.txt, sorry for the confusion, updated my question.

Comment: This thing is still giving me the same file not found exception, moved it to the `WEB-INF` and the updated path is `File entityFile = new File(getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/WEB-INF/EntitiesList/entities.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

1. First there is Typo error in your path
2. Second you should use getResourceAsStream() for loading file for writing.

Code example:

```
  InputStream input = getServletContext().
                              getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/EntityList/entities.txt");

  Files.copy(InputStream input , Path target) 
  //Or Files.copy(Path source, OutputStream out)
```

It seem easier to use FileInputStream, but it is better to use ResourceStream.
Read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2161583/8307755 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2308224/8307755

Comment: I'm writing to the file that is refereed as input(as per your code), how can I do it?sorry for the confusion, updated my question.