# JBoss: How to configure applications packaged in EARS?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, java-ee-6, jboss7.x, ear

We are currently developing a distributed JavaEE application. Several JBoss instances will be spreaded over several nodes and they have to communicate to each other.

Due to no knowledge about the actual deployment during development time we need a strategy how to configure the nodes without unpacking the EARs, changing the content and repacking them.

Currently we provide a system property via standalone.xml which points to the configuration directory and the application looks into it to read the configuration. This is not very fancy.

Is there an elegant way to put the configuration into the JBoss configuration directory, too, to read it from the via standard functionality? Is there another standard way to do it without additional system properties?

We currently use JBoss 7.1.0.Final and Java 1.6

**UPDATE**
I also found now a question qhich is quite similar, but not exactly what I want. Maybe it helps someone else: [How can I store Java EE configuration parameters outside of an EAR or WAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965061/how-can-i-store-java-ee-configuration-parameters-outside-of-an-ear-or-war)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the below link for Managed Domains, where you could manage the several JBoss instances seamlessly using a Domain Controller concept.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Core+management+concepts

Comment: I read the doc. Thanks, I is really insightful. (+1) But, I do not think it is already optimal. The configuration is for the JBoss instances. I would like to put the configuration into the JBoss without changing the JBoss configuration itself. For example: I would like to distribute an EAR to the customer with an additional configuration (maybe a property file?) and tell him just how to put this into the depoyment directory (the EAR) and what to do with this piece of configuration, what is the question. We are flexible then with adding and removing services on the different nodes.

Comment: Container implementor is not aware of what structure of the properties file you would be using. Configuration files provided by every server container is basically the properties file you were talking about, in addition to that it was standardized.But you would want to manage everything then you would need to write to do it that y way which is not feasible I think.